# --How do I get access to my container/store in this top level file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm just getting started with React/Redux and have everthing working fine with Redux when I test it.

However, I am not able to connect it into my actual application.

I assume I should use `connect()`, but I don't know how/where to.

```
// libraries
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import './redux/test.js';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, test) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div id = 'contents'>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(

  <Provider store={store}>
    <App></App>
  </Provider>

, app);
```

Comment: Have you read the docs? http://redux.js.org/

Answer (score 1):

You need to `connect` your component App.

By example let's assume you have value in your reducer named reducer in your store :

```
// libraries
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import './redux/test.js';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, test) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    // You can use data from props
    return (
      <div id = 'contents'>
        {this.props.data}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  // Bind your store state to the component data
  return {
    date: state.reducer.value,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  // Bind actions to your component
}

const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(

  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp></ConnectedApp >
  </Provider>

, app);
```

Comment: mapStateToProps will be a function that get data from your store state to a json object that can be used by the component. You can add your reducers in your example, I'll show you.

Comment: No. You will pickup the data that you want in your store and you will pass them to the component via the `connect`. The Component never manipulate directly the store.

Answer (score 1):

so what you need is to wrap App with the function returned by connect:

```
 const AppWithRedux = connect()(App);
 ReactDOM.render(

 <Provider store={store}>
   <AppWithRedux/>
 </Provider>,
 app);
```

But you can find a good example about how to integrate redux with react in the following link:

http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: `error: you must pass a component to the function returned by connect`

Comment: yup i was just typing quickly that's why i pointed out to the example... i think that you got my point...

Comment: So I don't have to pass anything to `connect()`? I would prefer not to, but I need access to `store.dispatch()` and `store.getState()`

Comment: exactly you don't need to unless you want an action or a property from the state. The reason is that needing only the dispach function is so common that by default it's passed if mapdispachoprops is undefined. On the other side if you want props from the state of the store you do need to pass mapstatetopros because that's a shorthand for subscribing to the store and it also provides some optimizations to prevent unnecessary re-renders

Comment: If this helped you, could you please accept my answer?